# Aggregate command in R to combine rows based on unique ID - output data structure?

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm sure there's a super-easy answer to this. I am trying to combine ratings on subjects based on their unique ID. Here is a test dataset (called Aggregate_Test)I created, where the ID is unique to the subject, and the StaticScore was done by different raters:

```
ID  StaticScore
1   6
2   7
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
3   4
4   5
```

After reading other posts carefully, I used aggregate to create the following dataset with new columns:

```
 StaticAggregate<-aggregate(StaticScore ~ ID, Aggregate_Test, c)
    > StaticAggregate

ID StaticScore.1 StaticScore.2
1  1             6             5
2  2             7             6
3  3             7             4
4  4             8             5
```

This data frame has the following str:

```
 > str(StaticAggregate)
    'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ ID         : num  1 2 3 4
     $ StaticScore: num [1:4, 1:2] 6 7 7 8 5 6 4 5
```

If I try to create a new variable by subtracting StaticScore.1 from StaticScore.2, I get the following error:

> Staticdiff<-StaticScore.1-StaticScore.2
>    Error: object 'StaticScore.1' not found

So, please help me - what is this data structure created by aggregate? A matrix? How could I convert StaticScore.1 and StaticScore.2 to separate variables, or barring that, what is the notation to subtract one from the other to create a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `dcast` to create a `wide` format from `long` and subtract those columns to create the 'StaticDiff'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Aggregate_Test), ID~paste0("StaticScore", rowid(ID)), value.var="StaticScore"
            )[, StaticDiff := StaticScore1 - StaticScore2]
```

---

Regarding the specific question about the `aggregate` behavior, we are just concatenating (`c`) the 'StaticScore' by 'ID'.  The default behavior is to create a `matrix` column in `aggregate`

```
StaticAggregate<-aggregate(StaticScore ~ ID, Aggregate_Test, c)
```

This can be checked by looking at the `str(StaticAggregate)`

```
str(StaticAggregate)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ ID         : int  1 2 3 4
#$ StaticScore: int [1:4, 1:2] 6 7 7 8 5 6 4 5
```

How do we change it to normal columns?

It can be done with `do.call(data.frame`

```
StaticAggregate <- do.call(data.frame, StaticAggregate)
```

Check the `str` again

```
str(StaticAggregate)
#'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ ID           : int  1 2 3 4
# $ StaticScore.1: int  6 7 7 8
# $ StaticScore.2: int  5 6 4 5
```

Now, we can do the calcuation as showed in the OP's post

```
StaticAggregate$Staticdiff <- with(StaticAggregate, StaticScore.1-StaticScore.2)
StaticAggregate
#  ID StaticScore.1 StaticScore.2 Staticdiff
#1  1             6             5          1
#2  2             7             6          1
#3  3             7             4          3
#4  4             8             5          3
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `str` output shown in the question indicates, `StaticAggregate` is a two column data.frame whose second column is a two column matrix, `StaticScore`.  We can display the matrix like this:

```
StaticAggregate$StaticScore
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    6    5
## [2,]    7    6
## [3,]    7    4
## [4,]    8    5
```

To create a new column with the difference:

```
transform(StaticAggregate, diff = StaticScore[, 1] - StaticScore[, 2])
##   ID StaticScore.1 StaticScore.2 diff
## 1  1             6             5    1
## 2  2             7             6    1
## 3  3             7             4    3
## 4  4             8             5    3
```

Note that there are no columns in `StaticAggregate` or in `StaticAggregate$StaticScore` named `StaticScore.1` and `StaticScore.2`.  `StaticScore.1` in the heading of the data.frame print output just denotes the first column of the `StaticScore` matrix.

The reason that the matrix has no column names is that the `aggregate` function `c` does not produce them.  If we change the original `aggregate` to this then they would have names:

```
StaticAggregate2 <- aggregate(StaticScore ~ ID, Aggregate_Test, setNames, c("A", "B"))
StaticAggregate2
##   ID StaticScore.A StaticScore.B
## 1  1             6             5
## 2  2             7             6
## 3  3             7             4
## 4  4             8             5
```

Now we can write this using the column names of the matrix:

```
StaticAggregate2$StaticScore[, "A"]
## [1] 6 7 7 8

StaticAggregate2$StaticScore[, "B"]
## [1] 5 6 4 5
```

Note that there is a significant advantage of the way R's `aggregate` works as it allows simpler access to the results -- the kth column of the matrix is the kth result of the aggregate function.  This is in contrast to having the k+1st column of the data.frame representing the kth result of the aggregate function.  This may not seem like much of a simplification here but for more complex problems it can be a significant simplification if you need to access the statistics matrix.  Of course, you can always flatten it to 3 columns if you want

```
do.call(data.frame, StaticAggregate)
```

but once you think about it for a while you may find that the structure it provides is actually more convenient.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their quick response and help.  It is helpful to see the different approaches to solving the problem.  The "do.call" function appears to do what I need, transforming the matrix columns into variables.  I can't find much documentation on it - any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: As mentioned although the do.call will flatten it it is usuablly not really desirable.